# jQuery simple mobile navigation swipe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation, swipe, touchscreen

I as using the following code to swipe next/previous with pages that has a href "next" and "prev"":

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
var keymap = {};

// LEFT
keymap[ 37 ] = "#prev";
// RIGHT
keymap[ 39 ] = "#next";

$( document ).on( "keyup", function(e) {
var href,
    selector = keymap[ e.which ];
// if the key pressed was in our map, check for the href
if ( selector ) {
    href = $( selector ).attr( "href" );
    if ( href ) {
        // navigate where the link points
        window.location = href;
    }
}
});
});
```

I am trying to add another script to allow the option to swipe using the same "next"/"prev" id, that works on mobiles like Android and iPhone.. etc.  I tried some of the following but can't get it to work..  Could you edit the script or show me a new one that does that (jsfiddle)?

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){

  var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
  var left = $('#prev').attr("href");
  var right = $('#next').attr("href");

  $("body").on("swiperight",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped right!");-->
    location.href=right;
  });                       
  $("body").on("swipeleft",function(){
    <!--alert("You swiped left!");-->
    location.href=left;
  });
});
  });
```

Or

```
var start = null;
 window.addEventListener("touchstart",function(event){
     document.body.innerHTML = "touch";
   if(event.touches.length === 1){
       document.body.innerHTML = " single touch";
      //just one finger touched
      start = event.touches.item(0).clientX;
    }else{
    start = null;
    }
  });

window.addEventListener("touchend",function(event){
    var offset = 100;//at least 100px are a swipe
    if(start){
        document.body.innerHTML = " single touch end";
      //just one finger touched
      var end = event.changedTouches.item(0).clientX;

      if(end > start + offset){
       //a left -> right swipe
      document.body.innerHTML = "next";
      }
      if(end < start - offset ){
       //a right -> left swipe
       document.body.innerHTML = " prev";
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Here is a demo: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-page/newyork.html

Comment: @deblocker Can this be implemented on the above code of id "next", "prev"?

Comment: Sorry, I believe You received no answers because it is hard to understand Your goal. Maybe You can try to post another question with Your requirements and the current status of Your implementation. Please, specify if You have a single-page or a multi-page model (see here: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)).

Comment: @deblocker They are simple html or php pages, that has codes like **<a href="afile.html" id="prev">** and **<a href="anotherfile.html" id="next">**